# Remote desktop (mstsc.exe) published through citrix cannot save credentials

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2003, citrix

We have published mstsc.exe (Remote Desktop) through Citrix.  Currently, users can check the "Allow me to save credentials" box, but this saved credential does not persist across sessions.

Since these settings are per user I had expected it to save the credentials.

The Citrix servers are running Windows 2003 and seem to be using Presentation Server 4.5.

Comment: Can you provide some info about the clients? thin clients? XP? win 7? are the users restricted users?

Comment: Users are accessing citrix via Windows(7/Vista) using either IE 8 or 9. The account they are using has administrative privleges on the target machines and their local, but not on the citrix servers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your local policy is not preventing this from happening.

You will need to save it for the same amount of time's you connect using a unique node.

ie. if you have RDP published across 4 nodes and you connect, it will need to be selected 4 times. then after that you will be set.